# MouseListener in background

Tags: java, mouse

Hi im creating an application for Mac so I can switch between applications using mission control and I want to do it with mouse button 4, 5 right, left but it only works when my application is in focus how can I make an mouse listener in the background so it works even If I am in as example safari

Comment: What you are describing isn't possible, as it could be called key-jacking. See Click-Jacking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Comment: How do Better Touch Tool do it then?